# What are the criteria for becoming "frequently in rooms"?

Tags: support, chat

This is not the most important topic, I know, but I would like to know what make a user counted as a frequent visitor in a chat room, in order for it to be listed on the chat [profile page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/754119/alon-eitan):

[image: frequently in rooms screenshot]

The title describe this link as "Rooms this user is active in regularly" and I'm active in one room that is already listed in the tooltip of my user, but perhaps that's because I flagged that room as favorite:

[image: user profile tooltip screenshot]

Comment: The rooms listed in the tooltip are the rooms you've joined (and haven't clicked "leave" for).

Comment: @JonClements This is for the second screenshot, right?

Comment: Yup - and I think the logic used for "frequent rooms" is in a post *somewhere* :)

Comment: @JonClements I searched before posting, and couldn't find any :| If someone will flag it as duplicate it'll mark it as helpful and close this post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at this MSE [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94146/how-is-chats-frequently-in-room-sorted) it appears that you must have spoken within the room in the last two weeks and have a least one percent in all messages here:

> This is how it currently works:
>
> > Take all users who
> >
> > 1. have spoken in the room within the last two weeks, and
> > 2. whose messages in the room are more than one percent of all messages here,
> >
> > and sort them (in descending order) by their percentage of activity in this room (as in 2.) divided by the how long ago they last spoke. Take the top ten resulting users.
>
> There's no guarantee this formula won't ever change, but it's been like this for a while, and its results are usually pretty good.

Comment: I guess that means there can only ever be at most 99 frequently in room people in any given room.

Comment: Yes! It seem easier to earn a tag gold badge than to be counted as a frequent visitor in a room

Comment: Unless you're a chatterbox @AlonEitan ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Only 10, right? It says it takes the top ten resulting users. That means it's practically impossible to be in a busy room frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the Javascript room almost all weekdays that I'm on work. Yet that "frequently in rooms" tab is empty at me. You can say that the feature doesn't work by checking the network traffic when you click on that button.

It tries to get data from (in my situation)

```
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2412895/karelg?tab=general&rooms=frequent
```

but it doesn't have a response. Since the request returned with `200 OK` HTTP status message, you can say that the server listens to that URL pattern but doesn't have a proper response for that. Or response stream is just empty, not supplied with the required data.

If you access the above URL by a HTTP GET request in the browser, you get the same page, with the right tab selected.

So my conclusion is that the necessary data isn't supplied during the creation of the webpage. (Missing method, empty variable, ...).

### EDIT

After Bugs' comment, it appears that the functionality works. In the javascript room, there is also a bot which has some rooms as frequently visited rooms.

So checked further and found out that some users get results when you check their frequent visited rooms tab, such as [rlemon](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/829835/rlemon), [kendall frey](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/785745/kendall-frey) and even [that dude's problematic relationship with steve](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/496680/steves-a-d) has results.

So it does work... The criteria's must be high then (based on # of comments?) because [this user](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/851498/florian-margaine) is now less frequent in the js room than I am, yet he has a result in his "frequently in rooms" tab.

Comment: Interesting... So it might just be a bug? Because I see that you're well active in that room with 275 messages posted only the last week

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. My reason being is that if you check a bot such as Queen or Natty you will see they frequent rooms. They post _a lot_ though so I do wonder what the criteria is.